# redirect from ngOnInit() and subsequent hooks causing reload of current component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router, ngoninit, routeparams

Trying to redirect to a new component from one of the hooks like ngOnInit(), ngAfterViewInit() based on a param supplied. The current component is executed multiple times if the router navigate line is hit.

**worked solution:**

```
setTimeout(() -> { this.router.navigate(link)); //recently upgraded angular 3 to 4.0.0 router
```

**main module :**

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: 'referrer/:vehicle/:referrer', component: ReferrerComponent },
        { path: 'referrer/:referrer', component: ReferrerComponent },
        { path: 'vehicle', component: vehicleComponent},
    ])
```

route: http://localhost:4200/#/referrer/vehicle1/referrer1

**ReferrerComponent:**

```
    ngOnInit() {

          this.routeObservable = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {

               if(params["referrer"]) { // do referrer stuff;}

               if(params["vehicle"] == "vehicle1") {

                  this.router.navigate('/vehicle'); //redirect to vehicle component
               }
         });
    }
```

As this happens only if a redirect actually happens, not sure where to put the re route (lifecycle) exactly.

Comment: Is it possible to do a plunker that demonstrates this?

Comment: If you add a method above the subscription assignment, but still inside the ngOnInit() { } block, is it called twice as well?  This would tell you if your subscription is just being retriggered, or if the actual lifecycle hook was being called twice (which would be very strange).

Comment: some way or the other your observable is triggered twice

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Angular's router, but my guess is the call to router.navigate triggers an update to the subscription its hosted inside of. So it immediately gets called again.

Comment: @diopside tried redirection in block outside and even in different hook ngAfterViewInit() based on a property set in ngOnInit(), but that triggered a reload too

Comment: Don't redirect in the block outside, just do some simple random function like console.log('') guaranteed to have no side effects, just to see if its being triggered.

Comment: @diopside it is loaded twice. it worked with a timeout is set on the redirect. May be with the version of angular route is a problem (4.0,0)

Comment: Yeah if lifecycle hooks like ngOnInit() are being called twice, that must be an issue with the router's dynamic component creation - afraid I can't be of much help there. I don't use the angular router. It frustrated me so much I wrote my own, lol